# Can't launch application in Android Studio (Ubuntu 14.04.3)

Tags: android, android-studio

I use latest Android Studio. I can't launch application on a virtual device. I use Android on AVD device of the same version as Minimum SDK version of application. Tried create app with no activity and blank activity. It tells that there are rendering problems and it can't instantiate some classes. And Gradle never infinitely builds something. 
[image]

...for now there is no messages about rendering (when I created without Activity), now it just builds infinitely:

[image]

Comment: Well, actually it is not an Building-Error, it is just a "Rendering Problem" try to select another Android-Api. 1) Open your Layout-XML-File and click on the Android-Icon top on the layout-view and change it.

Comment: If you mean like the screenshot so it's not a launch error it's just rendering, Try t change the theme to `AppTheme` from the menu above the phone in the ss. Also if you tried to launch the app in real emulator it will work correctly.

Comment: `What have you tried?` :D

Comment: @Shark tried create new projects, with different API versions, with/without skins, also see answers below and their comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These packages should be installed in the system:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5-dev lib32stdc++6
```

Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the rendering don't work, preview in Android Studio do not work propely.
Try to launch your app it should work.

Comment: Logs are here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Fc4d6wJs3YSGpzeEtrX1ZwM0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, can you just screenshot the exception ? Thank you.

Comment: You just create a blank activity in your project, right??

Comment: With blank activity there is rendering problem, and it's not launching; Now I tried create project with no activity - Gradle builds infinitely and logs are empty.

Comment: Rendering is not important do not pay attention for it.

Comment: You create a blank activity in a new project and you still have the gradle problem ?

Comment: Now I choosing "No Activity"

Comment: Yeah but you are not going to create it entirely, you are going to right-click choose activity section and blank activity ? Because you will have the same result. If gradle still loop, it is probably gradle the problem, so reinstall Android Studio maybe. The problem is not the rendering I am sure about this. Sorry I have no idea...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a build error, it's just the preview-renderer's problem. Those are normal, and you get used to them after a while...

Try building/deploying the project and seeing it runs just fine and looks as good as you made it. The only downside is that you can't preview how it's going to look in realtime before building/deployment.

EDIT:
If Gradle's taking it's sweet time, just restart Android Studio and do a File -> Invalidate cache and restart. Additionally, feel free to Clean / Rebuild your project. That should clean up all the nonsense that might get in the way.

The next Gradle build after that will really show you how long your project builds; subsequent builds should be shorter.

Comment: I waited 30+ minutes while it builds. "Invalidate cache" leads to freezing of IDE. Cleaning creates new "Gradle Build" process which doesn't stops.

Comment: Try updating your Gradle wrapper perhaps, looks like that might be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Your project shouldn't even compile since most probably you don't have those dependencies added to your project.

Go to your `build.gradle` file, look up the `dependencies` section and add the **Design** and **Support** library dependencies provided by Android like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    // The rest of your dependencies...
}
```

Re-sync your Gradle file and after that try to re-build your project.